# Using JSP tags efficiently for null value from java code

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

```
<% Object domName = request.getAttribute("domainName");
   String documentationLink = UMRACM.getDomainDocumentationMap().get(domName);
%>

<td><a href="<%=documentationLink%>"target="_blank"
 id="domainName_<s:property value="#rowstatus.index"/>"><s:property value="domainName" /></a></td>
```

Well I have used this **syntax** to print the `href` as **documentationLink** but I think this is not an efficient way to do so ,Hence a little help **required** in using the `code.

Is there a better way to do the logic part of the code.

Also if I get

> `documentationLink = null`

How shall I make the label **unclickable**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% Object domName = request.getAttribute("domainName");
   String documentationLink = UMRACM.getDomainDocumentationMap().get(domName);
%>
```

***Do this ^^^ to your Server Side.*** and put your retrieved `documentationLink` to either `session` or `request` scope. Like this:

```
   Object domName = request.getAttribute("domainName");
   String documentationLink = UMRACM.getDomainDocumentationMap().get(domName);
   request.setAttribute("documentationLink",documentationLink);
```

As I can see, you are using `Struts-tags`. So remove your scriptlets and try to use tags used in `Struts2`. Like this,

```
<td>
<s:if test="%{#request.documentationLink != null}">
<a href="<s:property value="#request.documentationLink"/>"target="_blank"
 id="domainName_<s:property value="#rowstatus.index"/>"><s:property value="domainName" />
</a>
</s:if>
<s:else>
<s:property value="domainName" />
</s:else>
</td>
```

Comment: this code work fine in setting the label as clickable or not clickable  and it is also able to set the attribute documentationLink but when I click on the href it redirects me to the same page

Comment: I edited it. I forgot to put `request.` in `<a href="<s:property value="#documentationLink">`

Comment: Also <s:property value="#request.documentationLink"/> ending this property with / , mine correct?

Answer (score 0):

One way to make lable **unclickable** by using **CSS**

**Html**

```
<a href="link.html" class="not-active">Link</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.not-active {
   pointer-events: none;
   cursor: default;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your `documentationLink` is null so you need to test it before the assign to `href`.

**Sample code**

```
 <% if(documentationLink != null){%>
    <a href="<%=documentationLink%>"target="_blank"
     id="domainName_<s:property value="#rowstatus.index"/>"><s:property value="domainName" /></a>
    <%}else{%>
    <a href="<%=documentationLink%>" style="opacity: .5;
pointer-events: none;">"target="_blank"
     id="domainName_<s:property value="#rowstatus.index"/>"><s:property value="domainName" /></a>
    <%}%>
```

you can try this one.